# httpclient multipart post with input streaming

Tags: android, post, httpclient, multipart

I'm looking for simple and clean solution for HTTP multipart post, which will send some Strings (form data) and several files with streaming support. (files needs to be streamed to avoid out of memory error)
I'd like to achieve this with the built-in "org.apache.httpclient" if possible.

I was able to create a clean solution with HttpURLConnection.
Despite all my efforts with this solution strings were sent with 8859-x encoding instead of UTF-8.

EDIT: My code is available at [MultiPart with HttpURLConnection source](http://www.bravosierra.info/HttpHelperMultiPart.txt)

I created an output stream with this code:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = setupConnection();
dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
```

After this I just wrote the data with dataOutputStream.writeBytes

If i could get an outputstream from httpclient it would be great, however it seems it works a different way.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, your code is no more available at your URL. Can you repost it here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just created a simple solution for this: [android_multipart_entity](https://github.com/vitkhudenko/android_multipart_entity).

It's free (including for commercial usage), however if this is possible please keep references to me inside of my classes.

It's designed to be used with the built in Android `HttpClient`. Sample usage code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yourhost.com");
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
entity.addPart(new StringPart("name", "yourname"));
File imageFile = // .. get your image file
entity.addPart(new FilePart("picture", imageFile, null, "image/jpeg"));
httppost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

**EDIT:**

I reviewed your MultiPart with HttpURLConnection code. You get UTF-8 issue because of `DataOutputStream` usage. API says for that class:

> Wraps an existing OutputStream and writes **big-endian** typed data to it. Typically, this stream **can be read in by DataInputStream**.

This class just does not suit your needs. In order to read the data you would have to have its direct opposite - `DataInputStream` on the other end.

So my advice would be to use plain `OutputStream`. And write bytes to it. Smth like this:

```
outputStream.write(partSeparator.getBytes());
outputStream.write(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + parameter.getKey() + "\"" + lineEnd).getBytes());
outputStream.write(("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd).getBytes());
outputStream.write(("Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" + lineEnd).getBytes());
outputStream.write(lineEnd.getBytes());
outputStream.write(parameter.getValue().getBytes("UTF-8")); // <= this is it!
outputStream.write(lineEnd.getBytes());
outputStream.write(partSeparator.getBytes());
```

Comment: Hm, I successfully use this. What exactly goes wrong? What errors do you get in the LogCat? Could it be a server issue? Do you specify internet permission in the android manifest?

Comment: Could be a server issue. I can post the files with my class which relies on HTTPURLConnection. I composed the multipart communication manually there. The server requires a line break before the file binary data, I don't know if this is standard. The server is a php server. I have to solve this asap. I will look into the code deeply.

Comment: To answer your question, no error at all, just the files didn't arrive to the server

Comment: @Sandor: Sorry, but I didn't catch you - have you tried my solution or not? It sounds like not. I successfully use my solution with php and ruby servers, so I can guarantee it works.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough. I tried your solution, it works for the strings, however the files did not appear on server side.

Comment: With my solution which uses the httpurlconnection instead of httpclient: the file upload works, the strings part works, however strings are sent in 8859 instead of UTF-8.

Comment: @Sandor: This might be just related to file parameter naming or smth like that. The reason should be simple. And again - id does work for me, so it sounds to me very odd it doesn't work for you. Have you checked the logs on server?

Comment: I belive it works, that's why I marked it as answer and voted up.
Unfortunately I cannot access the server logs currently.
The file parameter name should be ok altough it contains "[" and "]".

Comment: @Sandor: :) sorry, I might have been too "insisting" with my solution. Feel free to edit your post and put the code where you send strings to HTTPURLConnection, so maybe I can help you with UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks Arhimed, I think your code is better, because it uses the apache httpclient which is indeed better than the plain java HttpURLconnection. The only issue is that your code is not works out of the box for me, which may be server related issue. I made an edit on the question and linked my original class for multipart post.

Comment: outputStream.write solved the problem
Big thanks goes to Arhimed

Comment: Big ups for this code Arhimed, worked like a charm as far as i can tell! huge help in streaming a large file off the SD card to a server with strings in the body also, and not causing OOM errors! thanks again