# What is android's equivalent for this curl operation?

Tags: android, curl

I'm currently using the following linux command to submit files to a website:

```
curl --form file=@s1.png --form someparameter=somevalue http://api.website.com/upload.php
```

I have never made an android app before.  But is there an equivalent operation in the android SDK?  Or since android development is done with Java, perhaps there's something to do this?  If so, what is it?

Comment: What is the modern way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some people like to use [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

You won't get something in one line, but it has all that you would need.

If you need something more comprehensive, then [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) would be up your alley.

Update:

Avoid HttpClient! [It is deprecated](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client). The most commonly recommended Http Library right now is [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).

Comment: How can you add Form fields to a HttpURLConnenction object?

Comment: I recommend you investigate [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). There is no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this can probably be created based on the answer to [httpclient multipart post with input streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173914/httpclient-multipart-post-with-input-streaming) from what I can tell.